# OS X version for Tesseract-OCR?

Tags: ios, macos, ocr, tesseract

As ios dev, the OCR  ( https://github.com/gali8/Tesseract-OCR-iOS ) is quite good for iPhone devices.

How can easily get the OS X OCR version from this code ? Thanks,

Answer (score 2):

You can compile tesseract and leptonica by yourself in Xcode. The resulting binary can be used in Mac and iOS as well. Check the Xcode examples here:

https://github.com/mcku/tesseract-osx
https://github.com/mcku/leptonica-osx

Answer (score 0):

I got a version of Tesseract for my Mac 10.9 from the repository here:  http://code.google.com/p/tesseract-ocr/downloads/list.

The documentation was here: http://code.google.com/p/tesseract-ocr/wiki/ReadMe

I did have download the specific language, as well.

Answer (score 0):

The current home of Tesseract-OCR is [here](https://github.com/tesseract-ocr/tesseract/wiki) on GitHub.

They recommend installing on OSX using macports or homebrew. However, the current version available in macports is only 3.02 (same as on the archived google code site). If you require the more recent 3.04, you need to compile it yourself (just follow the [instructions on the wiki page](https://github.com/tesseract-ocr/tesseract/wiki/Compiling)).